# Trouble getting custom pin to show in Bing Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, bing-maps

I'm showing using a bing map on my web page and I'm trying to use a custom pin for the location but it won't show up. My project is ASP.Net Core, My image is stored in wwwroot/images and this JavaScript is in wwwroot/js/site.js. I'm not sure if my path is just wrong or what.

```
var renderRequestsMap = function (divIdForMap, requestData) {
if (requestData) {
    var bingMap = createBingMap(divIdForMap);
    addRequestPins(bingMap, requestData);
}
}

function createBingMap(divIdForMap) {
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(
    document.getElementById(divIdForMap), {
        credentials: BingMapKey,
        zoom: 2
});

// tile url from Iowa Environmental Mesonet of Iowa State University
var urlTemplate = 'https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-{timestamp}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png';
var timestamps = ['900913-m50m', '900913-m45m', '900913-m40m', '900913-m35m', '900913-m30m', '900913-m25m', '900913-m20m', '900913-m15m', '900913-m10m', '900913-m05m', '900913'];
var tileSources = [];
for (var i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
    var tileSource = new Microsoft.Maps.TileSource({
        uriConstructor: urlTemplate.replace('{timestamp}', timestamps[i])
    });
    tileSources.push(tileSource);
}
var animatedLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.AnimatedTileLayer({ mercator: tileSources, frameRate: 500 });
map.layers.insert(animatedLayer);

return map;
}

function addRequestPins(bingMap, requestData) {
var locations = [];
$.each(requestData, function (index, data) {
    var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(data.lat, data.long);
    locations.push(location);
    var order = index + 1;
    alert(data.pinurl);
    var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, { icon: 'images/low-risk-south-pin.png' });
    bingMap.entities.push(pin);
});
var rect = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locations);
bingMap.setView({ bounds: rect, padding: 80 });
}
```

Also when the map loads it is super zoomed into my pin and whatever I do I can't get it to start with a far out zoom.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, take a look at the network trace. Here you should see where the images are being requested from and will help you verify if it is requesting from the right location.

As for the zooming, you are calculating in the LocationRect from the locations of the pins and then setting the map view based on that. Sounds like that is working as expected. If you don't want to zoom in on your pins, remove that code.